# I want to edit a dataframe based on values in another dataframe, resulting in a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes:

```
data_1 = [['Michael', 40, 'Brown', 1], ['Dwight', 38, 'Brown', 2], ['Jim', 36, 'Blonde', 3]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Hair Color', 'IQ'])
print(df_1)

       Name  Age Hair Color  IQ
    0  Michael   40      Brown   1
    1   Dwight   38      Brown   2
    2      Jim   36     Blonde   3


data_2 = [['Michael', 'Age', 42], ['Dwight', 'Hair Color', 'Red'], ['Jim', 'IQ', 135]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns=['Name', 'Change', 'Age'])
print(df_2)

      Name      Change  Age
0  Michael         Age   42
1   Dwight  Hair Color  Red
2      Jim          IQ  135
```

I want to somehow join them so the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
      Name  Age Hair Color  IQ
0  Michael   42      Brown   1
1   Dwight   38        Red   2
2      Jim   36     Blonde 135
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I want to somehow join them so the resulting dataframe looks like this:

      Name  Age Hair Color  IQ
0  Michael   42      Brown   1
1   Dwight   38        Red   2
2      Jim   36     Blonde 135

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

`pivot` & `combine_first` for updating

```
df_2.pivot(index='Name', columns='Change', values='Age')\
    .reindex(df_1['Name'])\
    .combine_first(df_1.set_index('Name')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
    Name    Age Hair Color  IQ
0   Michael 42  Brown       1
1   Dwight  38  Red         2
2   Jim     36  Blonde      135
```